# What version of Java does Cassandra 3 require

Tags: cassandra

The recommended version of Java [for Cassandra 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28912016/545127) was Java 7. But which version is recommended or required for Cassandra 3 (specifically, version 3.5)?

Some information suggests that Java 7 or Java 8 are required; that is, that Java 7 is still OK:

- The Cassandra Wiki [says](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted#Step_0:_Prerequisites_and_Connecting_to_the_Community):

> Cassandra requires the most stable version of Java 7 or 8

- The [change log for Cassandra 3.5](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=CHANGES.txt;hb=refs/tags/cassandra-3.5) does not mention changing the required JRE. It does have a change ([CASSANDRA-7028](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7028)) to "Allow compilation in java 8". But *allow* is not the same as *require*.

Comment: I am answering my own question, as is encouraged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cassandra 3.0+ requires Java 8.

- The `cassandra-env.sh` script, used by the `cassandra` shell script, examines the JVM version and refuses to run if the JVM version is before 1.8.
- If you try to run code directly using one of the classes of the `cassandra-all.jar` using a Java 7 environment you will get a [`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` complaining of `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0).
- The `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file in the JAR indicates it was compiled using a Java 8 compiler: `Created-By: 1.8.0_45-b14 (Oracle Corporation)`.
- The [Datastax announcement about Cassandra 3](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/features.html) says that it requires Java 8.

In conclusion, the Cassandra Wiki is wrong and the Cassandra change log is misleading.

Comment: I've updated the Wiki, thanks for pointing that out.  Instead of the changelog, you should be looking at NEWS.txt, specifically the "Upgrading" section for your version (and any versions you may skip).  For 3.0, this says "3.0 requires Java 8u40 or later.".

Comment: You'll run into a similiar issue with JDK 10 since they changed the naming scheme -- the cassandra-env.sh script's parsing is naively assuming the old naming convention.