# Where to change jvm options for Cassandra on MAC

Tags: java, cassandra

I Installed cassandra 3.11.4 using Brew. `cassandra -v` suggests me the cassandra is installed. But when I tried to do `cassandra -f`, I'm getting following error:

```
[0.001s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.4/libexec/logs/gc.log instead.
intx ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1 ]
Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Installed JDK Version: 11

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It may be related to java version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37297330

Comment: Where can I get jvm.options for JDK 11 on Mac?

Comment: Try to install java 8, you can have multiple versions installed alongside: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26252591. See the most voted answer, you can use brew to do this.

Comment: FYI- Cassandra 3.x has only been tested on Java 8.

Comment: Cassandra 3.11.4 supports Java 11, we have been testing it for the last months and have been taking advantage of the zgc garbage collection with good results so far

Answer (score 2):

The issue that you are having is that the `jvm.options` file has the default policy `-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42`, if you are using Java 11 you should comment it. This file is located in the same directory where you can find the [cassandra.yaml configuration file](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html).

Also note that if you are using Java 11, you will need to replace all the gc-related settings with `-Xlog:gc:/<your cassandra log path>/gc.log`